# Distance Sorting Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm a little issue with sorting entity distances. For an example, 13 mile would come first and than 2 mile would come second. Here is my code:

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
        sortedArray = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
            NSString * first= [(GooglePlacesObject*)a distanceInMilesString];
            NSString * second = [(GooglePlacesObject*)b distanceInMilesString];
            return [first compare:second];
        }
        ];

        for (GooglePlacesObject * place in sortedArray) {
            Model * model = [Model fetchFromGooglePlacesObject:place];
            [self.gFoundModels addObject:model];


        }
    }
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: So what's the issue with your code? What's the output, and what's the desired output?

Comment: Is `GooglePlacesObject` a custom class? Can we see its implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're sorting strings, so 13 comes first, because "13" is less than "2" when comparing strings in default comparator.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you should not be comparing strings but instead converting them to floats and returning for which is bigger.

EDIT:

From my understanding, it's something like this

```
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [objects sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a,id b)
{
    float first=[[(GooglePlacesObject*)a distanceInMilesString] floatValue];
    float second=[[(GooglePlacesObject*)b distanceInMilesString] floatValue];
    return first>second;
}];
```